# how to use libusb on android (7.0+, not root) ? libusb_init() is always return -1;

Tags: android, libusb

now,I want to use libusb(1.0.20) on my phone to transfer custom protocol data,I have compiled it into so files through the NDK and imported it into my AS project, but when i use 'libusb_init()' this method，it always returns -1 (input/output error). (I use my phone to connect to another, or connect to a usb)
do any friends know what's wrong with my operation? i need your guidances, thanks！！！！

Comment: On a non-rooted device, it's highly unlikely the OS will grant you access to the raw USB driver

Comment: emmmm, I tried it on a different phone, the system is android 5.1(non-rooted), and it returns 0  (success) ,  it still return 0 without connecting the device,  is it a libusb compile problem? or is it normal to display success without connected devices?  thank you very much for your answer  :)